# Google Map API reverse geocoding from KML Layer

Tags: maps, kml, layer

I have a KML Map Layer on google map which contains the Administrative boundaries of an administrative unit called "BLOCKS".Each Block has different ID. How can i get the ID of the Block if i get the Longitude and Latitude of the Location using my mobile?

Answer (score 1):

That information is not currently accessible with KmlLayer.  If you import your KML into Fusion Tables, you can query the table and determine which polygon a Lat/Lng point is in (using ST_INTERSECT with a small CIRCLE)

Another option would be to use a third party parser like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/), but if your KML is complex, that will have performance issues.